# How does JavaScript infer instance types at runtime?

Tags: javascript, types, runtime

When writing JavaScript I always took for granted that adding two integers together resulted in another integer. Or that adding two strings together would result in the concatenation. But I got to thinking, how does the language determine the types of instances behind the scenes prior to performing operations using those instances?

```
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var fourStr = 'four';
var floaty = 1.5;

//this results in an integer
var three = one + two;           //3

//but this results in a string
var result = fourStr + one;      //'four1'

//and this results in a float
var floatenized = one + floaty;  //2.5
```

**Does the runtime just determine the instance types and then reference some sort of internal type precedence or something?** Can anyone explain exactly **how** these operations are performed by the runtime when instances of differing types are combined?

Comment: As ManseUK has pointed out when combining a string with a number the string takes precendence therefore the number is converted to a string first then the two are concatenated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ecmascript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) describes exactly how operators like `+` (section 11.6.1) act with different types.

Relevant for your example:

- (number) `+` (number): result will be the sum of the floats
- (string) `+` (number): result will be the concatenation of the string and the string represantation of the number
- (number) `+` (string): result will be the concatenation of the string represantation of the number and the string

But the `+` can also act as a unary operator to transform a string into a number, as like as the binary `-` operator does (e.g.: `+"4"+5==9`, `5-"4"==1`).

The type conversion algorithms are described in section 9 of the spec. How an environment should store the types of primitives and objects is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a number to a variable

```
var one = 1;
//or
var floaty = 1.5;
```

the value type is a number .... When you assign a string to a variable

```
var fourStr = 'four';
```

the value type is string. When you add a string and a number it converts the number to a string then concatenates the 2 strings

[See the values section of this doc from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals)

Comment: Noting that variables don't have a type, their value does. ;-)

Comment: This isn't really telling me anything I don't already know. I know that the conversions are taking place, my question was more how and by what means is the conversion taking place in JavaScript.

Comment: @KodeKreachor the `+` symbol is shorthand for concatenation when used with a string - the `toString()` method is used to convert the number to a string ....

Comment: @ManseUK thanks for your answers, maybe I'm not stating myself clearly. How does the runtime know that a number needs to be converted into a string when it is concatenated w/ another string? Does it make a list of all the types in the expression and then, if any strings exist, converts them all into strings? How is this happening behind the scenes?

Comment: @KodeKreachor I assume it checks each of the types and converts all to strings if a string is found - you would have to look at the source (JavaScript) to verify

Comment: Yep, that was my question. I made the same assumption but I wanted to know for sure.